# How do you redirect to a route passing in a additional parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

my controller code:

```
public function edit(Request $request, Posts $posts) {
        $validatedRequests = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'description' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'price' => 'required|integer|max:255|'
        ]);    

        $posts->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price    
        ]);    

        $posts->save();

        *return redirect(route('singelPost', ['post'=> $posts->id]))->with('mssg', 'updates successfully');* 
    }
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/post/{post:id}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('singlePost');
```

This is the error i get:

> *Missing required parameter for [Route: showEditForm] [URI: post/{post}/editForm] [Missing parameter: post].*

Comment: what relation does the route `showEditForm` have to the code you are showing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have made a mistake code/syntax? Try this:

```
return redirect()->route('singlePost', $posts->id)->with('mssg', 'updates successfully');
```